# Prove by using coprimeness

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image: question]

I have this question and I totally don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: I tried to use induction, and I verified the base case when n=1, and it works. However, I failed to prove the induction conclusion. Then I tried to do just direct proof, but I still can't solve it.

Comment: There ought to be some conditions on $p$ and $q$. For example, $\operatorname{GCD}(p,q) = 1$. Otherwise, the above is not true (just take $p = q > 1$ and $a_k = (-1)^k$ for some odd $n$).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put gcd(p,q)=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more explicit:

Suppose
$r = \frac{p}{q}$
is a root of the polynomial
$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n$,
where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.
Then
$a_0+a_1r+a_2r^2+...+a_nr^n=0$,
.

Substituting for $r$,
we get
$$a_0
+a_1\frac{p}{q}+a_2\frac{p^2}{q^2}+...+a_n\frac{p^n}{q^n}
=0.$$
Multiplying all terms by $q^n$,
we get
$$a_0q^n
+a_1pq^{n-1}+a_2p^2q^{n-2}+...+a_np^n
=0.$$

We can rewrite this in two ways
to get the results you want.

The first way is
$$-a_0q^n
=a_1pq^{n-1}+a_2p^2q^{n-2}+...+a_np^n
.$$
$p$ divides each term
of the right side of this equation,
so it divides their sum.
Therefore,
$p$ divides the left side, also.
Since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime,
$p$ must divide $a_0$.

For the second way,
write the equation as
$$a_0q^n
+a_1pq^{n-1}+a_2p^2q^{n-2}+...+a_{n-1}p^{n-1}q
=-a_np^n
.$$
Again,
$q$ divides the left side,
so it must divide the right side.
Therefore, as before,
$q$ must divide $a_n$
since it is relatively prime
to $p$.

Comment: Thank you, I have one question about this proof. "p divides each term of the right side of this equation, so it divides their sum. ", is this because we can take p out as a common factor? Then, I cannot understand why we can skip to "p divides the left side".

Comment: LHS=RHS, so any factor of RHS must be a factor of LHS.

Comment: Oh right.. I didn't see that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply through by $q^n$.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know what to do. Could you tell me what method should I use? Like induction?

Comment: What you should do is what vadim said to do. What happens when you multiply through by $q^n$? What equation do you get? Write it down! and think about it! and let us know what you see.

Comment: I get -a0q^n=a1pq^n-1+.....+anp^n